Intel wifi on DISABLED after upgrade to 24
I recently upgraded to (k)Ubuntu 24 and I'm usually on wired internet so I did not notice, but the upgrade seems to have disabled the WiFi.
Since 22, my /etc/netplan/01-network-all.yaml looks like this
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

so netplan hands over to NetworkManager, but the WiFi does not show up in nmtui.
rfkill | grep wl says:
1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

also lspci | grep WiFi says
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 10)

and even likely culprit iwlwifi looks compliant:
[    4.673071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.679651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x2816, cnv-id 0x1000100 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    4.679682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev a370/0034, rev=0x312, rfid=0x105110
[    4.692513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    4.692518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    4.692520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    4.692522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    4.692524] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    4.692525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    4.692528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    4.692530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    4.692531] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    4.692533] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    4.692534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    4.692536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    4.692537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    4.692539] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    4.692541] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    4.692542] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    4.692544] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    4.693590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.7e3e4b69.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.401216] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x312
[    5.451110] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 20:79:18:63:88:a0, OTP minor version: 0x4
[    5.523347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    9.683386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0

so it looks like the hardware is properly detected.
However, the output of lshw -C network is
 *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 20:79:18:63:88:a0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic firmware=46.7e3e4b69.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:152 memory:a541c000-a541ffff

for the WiFi, iwconfig returns
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

and ip link returns
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:79:18:63:88:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3

Does anyone know why I can see the wireless hardware, but the network card is DISABLED, Not-Associated and DORMANT?
